# Constructing or composing my own blocks or imps

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, imp

#### **Question**

Does objective-c have any kind of functionality which allows me to compose my own blocks or `IMP`s on the fly?

By that I mean let me link together arbitrary code snippets into a single block (and then perform `imp_implementationWithBlock`) or just get an assembled `IMP` straight up.

#### **Pseudocode**

```
(IMP) linkExistingBlock:LBExistingBlock With:^{

}
```

or

```
(IMP) linkExistingBlock:LBExistingBlock With:LBAnotherBlock
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "on the fly". Presumably you're thinking of doing something during runtime, but where are these "arbitrary code snippets" coming from? Can you give some kind of at least pseudocode example?

Comment: Added the ideal method signature for a solution to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two Blocks, just call them. Further, Blocks are objects, and [can be put into `NSArray`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676840/an-array-of-blocks/11676900#11676900). Then you can enumerate the array and invoke its contents.

```
for( dispatch_block_t block in arrayOfBlocks ){
    block();
}
```

or

```
[arrayOfBlocks enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(dispatch_block_t block, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        block();
}];
```

If you have `IMP`s, those are just function pointers -- they can be put into a C array, or wrapped in `NSValue`s and put into a Cocoa array. You just need to cast them before you try to call them.

For your example method signature:

```
- (dispatch_block_t)blockLinkingExistingBlock: (dispatch_block_t)firstBlock withBlock: (dispatch_block_t)secondBlock
{
    dispatch_block_t linker = ^{ firstBlock(); secondBlock();};
    // if compiling with ARC
    return linker;
    // otherwise
    // return [[linker copy] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in, but you can just create a block that simply executes a series of blocks by calling them.